# How do I fix "'struct _IO_FILE' has no member named '_file'"?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I have a version of a program that used to compile to a `*.o` file, but now it does not, and gives a compiler error.

I have tried to compile my code with gcc compiler on Linux, and the compile fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isatty();

long isatty_(lio_number)
long *lio_number;
{
        int file_desc;

        if ((*lio_number)==5)
        {
                file_desc = stdin->_file;
                return isatty(file_desc);
        }
        else
                return 0;
}
```

I expect the command `gcc -c isatty.c` to yield `isatty.o` but it does not. Instead, I get this message:

```
isatty.c: In function ‘isatty_’:
isatty.c:11: error: ‘struct _IO_FILE’ has no member named ‘_file’
```

Comment: Never use any members of the `FILE` structure. Instead, use `fileno(stdin)`.

Comment: The `lio_number` argument is peculiar.  Can you show at least one example of the code that uses this function, please?

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It’s written in an ancient style of C (and is non-portable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use any members of the `FILE` structure.

Use `fileno(stdin)` instead of `stdin->_file`.

The member `_file` is a MinGW-specific name for the file descriptor, while `fileno` is a widely-supported POSIX-compliant function.

Along with that, you may want to `#include <unistd.h>` instead of defining `isatty` explicitly.

If you're limited to writing your code this way for some reason, don't expect it to be portable. Otherwise, this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

long isatty_(long *lio_number)
{
        int file_desc;

        if (*lio_number == 5)
        {
                file_desc = fileno(stdin);
                return isatty(file_desc);
        }
        else
        {
                return 0;
        }
}
```

What this changes is that it includes `unistd.h` which provides a declaration for `isatty`, it includes the types of the arguments within the function definition, and it uses `fileno(stdin)` instead of `stdin->_file`, of which the former is much more portable. It also improves the formatting so others can read your code if they need to.

Answer (score 3):

Modernize the code. The original seems to be targeting some ancient Unix. This should work on more recent POSIX-compliant systems, since virtually every such system should provide the [fileno()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fileno.html) function. Changing the code to standard C is also a good idea.

So use `fileno()`, include `<unistd.h>` instead of forward declaring `isatty()`, and use standard C function parameter declarations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

long isatty_(long *lio_number)
{
    if (*lio_number == 5)
    {
        return isatty(fileno(stdin));
    }
    return 0;
}
```